# Hydronic kickspace heater on same zone as cast iron radiators?

Tags: hvac, kitchens, heating, hydronic

Small older home that has in-wall cast iron radiators throughout the house in a single zone. Hot water not steam. When the kitchen was remodeled years ago the cast iron radiator was removed because it would have been behind the new fridge location. The idea was that it would be moved to a different location but years later it's still on the todo list.

I have been exploring other options but it seems like the easiest most cost effective thing to do would be to add a kickspace hydronic heater under one of the kitchen cabinets.

Is it okay to mix the kickspace heater on the same single zone as the cast iron radiators?

Some additional info if it factors in... The smallest kickspace heater I can find is almost twice the BTU needed for that room. The 1st floor where the kitchen is is all open and generally colder than upstairs.

The main heating pipe is 1" copper tubing I believe or there abouts. For each cast iron radiator there's a venturi T fitting on the supply and return 1/2" copper piping. I was going to plumb the kickspace heater into the existing supply and return pipes that go to the old radiator which is removed and capped off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix a kick-space heater with cast iron radiators in the same zone but it is not recommended. My choice would be a "Beacon Morris". It comes in 3 models (sizes), and It has a built in thermostat that allows the fan to run when the water temperature is above 110 degrees F. The best installation would be with a monoflo tee on both the supply and return lines, however one on the supply will still work. I am guessing that the systems pump runs all the time and is controlled by a reverse acting control that turns the pump on when the water temp. is above about 110 degrees F. You may desire to add a thermostat to control the fan's heater to stop heat over-runs. For best results I have also installed Danfoss radiator valves on each radiator to control the heat in each room.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand on why it's not a recommended setup and what I would experience if I did it that way? Adding a different zone would be very difficult/costly. Cast iron baseboard rads probably prefferred but costly and difficult to plumb. I saw Danfoss has a non-electric valve with remote sensor that I might add in the future if necessary. Looks like they pop on to existing valve stem? Leaving the venturri t's on the supply and return would be similar to monoflows right?

Comment: The venturi tees are the same as Monoflo tees. The Danfoss valves use their own valves not the existing valves. Google Danfoss, and you will see the valves and thermostats. They run about $ 80.00 a set "valve and thermostat"  depending on where you buy them. They work great. For operation, cast iron rads heat by  both radiation (think the sun) and by convection. The kick space heater heats by convection only, so you may need more heat than you think you will need. If you add a thermostat then you could install a larger unit than figured and not have to worry about not enough or too little heat

Comment: I took a quick look at the RA 200 Thermsotatic Operators and thought they could install on any valve stem but guess only the Danfoss valve bodies. The kickspace heater is about twice the btu capacity I need. I might install the kickspace heater without the thermostatic valve but put a couple of ball valves on the supply and return lines to make it easier to add one in the future if necessary.

Comment: By the way, I did not mean to install a thermostatic valve, I was referring to a wall thermostat to cycle the fan on and off to control the room temperature. That was why I said that the size of the heater would not matter if a thermostat was installed. You may not get the heat out of the kick-space heater you require since cast iron rads may run at a lower temperature than you used to size the heater. Cast iron rads are a great way to heat as long as you don't mind the look of the rad.

Comment: Thought the thermostatic valve made more sense since restricting the water flow would keep the fan from cycling too. Double checked and the venturi tee is only on one side. Might be return side unless I'm looking at it wrong. Can you elaborate on what I would expect with it on the same zone? Would it cause problems? With no radiator currently in the kitchen would the kitchen be more comfortable than now? Would it cause problems in other rooms? I might go ahead and put in a couple of zone valves and thermostat just for the kitchen depending on my budget when I do it.

Comment: If you use a Beacon Morris kick space heater I would buy one larger than what you need to supply the kitchen  and wire in a wall thermostat since you do not know what the water temperature supplied to the kitchen will be on a given day. Usually you need only only 1 venturi tee on either the supply or return if the rad is above the circulating line and 2 tees if the rad is below the circulating line. You can see which way the water flows from the top of the boiler out to the system and back to the pump and bottom of the boiler. I can't say how the kitchen will heat but should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential hazard with putting a cast iron radiator on the same zone.

My boiler distributes baseboard heat water at 140 degrees F.  This temp is safe for copper tubes bristling with fins in a protective cover.  But direct contact with thick metal at 140 degrees may cause burns.

As a comparison grab the manifold in in your mechanical room.

This is a borderline case.  I routinely pick up burning logs in my stove, picking my grab points with care, but my hands are well calloused from work.  Older people and children with thin skin and/or low blood flow to dissipate heat may get burned.

On the ohter hand: They make fabulous towel warmers.

Comment: Wouldn't the kick space heater be in the order of "copper tubes bristling with fins in a protective cover", while the radiator would be cast iron filled with hot water? In that case, the assumption is that the water running through the radiators is at a temp appropriate for them, while the kick space heater would be supplied with under temp water...